# perl + combine exec command with perl one liner line

Tags: linux, shell-script, solaris, perl

I have the following short perl script `rename.pl`. How can I translate this script to one liner perl syntax? And how to combine the perl one liner in `find` command?

#### `rename.pl`

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

$op = shift;
for (@ARGV) {
  $was = $_;
  eval $op;
  die $@ if $@;
  rename($was,$_) unless $was eq $_;
}
```

My current `find` syntax:

```
find /tmp -name "*$NAME*" -exec \
  ./rename.pl \
  's/\Q$ENV{NAME_THAT_WE_WANT_TO_CHANGE}\E/$1$ENV{NEW_NAME}$2/' {} +
```

The `find` syntax  that I want to build:

```
find /tmp -name "*$NAME*" -exec \
  < perl one liner line ....... > \
  's/\Q$ENV{NAME_THAT_WE_WANT_TO_CHANGE}\E/$1$ENV{NEW_NAME}$2/' {} +
```

Comment: OTOH, you could use `File::Find` in the script turning the whole thing into a simple command.  I know that seems crazy as you will not get to spend as much time typing and making mistakes, but... $0.02

Comment: @goldilocks, if he's not familiar with `perl` (he copy-pasted that perl code), then he's more likely to make mistakes with that, and it's probably going to be less efficient. He could use `mmv` or `zmv` that are designed for that kind of task (or even `rename`, an off the shelf `perl` script for that).

Comment: Good point. I had taken *"I have the following short perl script"* to mean something like "this is my script, it works" (and now I want to make it a one liner).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Simply give the content of the script as an argument following `-e`:

```
find .... -exec perl -e '
  $op = shift;
  for (@ARGV) {
    $was = $_;
    eval $op;
    die $@ if $@;
    rename($was,$_) unless $was eq $_;
  }' s/a/b/g {} +
```

You can condense it to:

```
find ... -exec perl -e '$op=shift;for(@ARGV){$was=$_;eval$op;die$@if$@;rename$was,$_ unless$was eq$_}' s/a/b/g {} +
```

But that doesn't help legibility.

Comment: not clearly how to set your first example in the find syntax ? , can you give me full example ?

Comment: WOW - this is great , thanx

Comment: this is the last update or you need to test your syntax to be sure that its work ?